# Issue with Laravel Migrations and Foreign Keys

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I am currently receiving the following error when I run my migrations:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'saferides.#sql-189_4bc' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table `rides` add constraint rides_car_id_foreign foreign key (`car_id`) references `car` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

After reading a lot of issues about errors of this nature in Laravel, I have done the following to avoid it:

- Not reference a primary key with a foreign key until the primary key is created ( I make sure of this by keeping my table creations and foreign key assignments in separate migrations in the following order creation -> keys
- Make sure the primary key and the foreign key are of the same type (unsigned int(10))
- Explicitly state the storage engine to be InnoDB

Currently, I have my migrations set up so that the tables are created first:

```
// Up function for cars table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cars', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        // Explicitly state storage engine
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        // Primary Key
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();

        // Other columns
        $table->string('car_num');
        $table->string('available_seats');
    });
}
```

Then my next table...

```
// Up function for rides table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('rides', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        // Explicitly state storage engine
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        // Primary Key
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();

        // Other columns
        $table->boolean('completed')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('no_show')->default(0);

        // Indexes to foreign keys
        $table->integer('car_id')->unsigned()->index();
   });
}
```

After all my tables are created, I add my foreign keys to the tables.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('rides', function(Blueprint $table) 
    {
        $table->foreign('car_id')
              ->references('id')->on('car')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: what is table 'saferides' ? Its in the error but you dont mention it in your code - confusing

Comment: saferides is the name of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone in the future is having this issue, I managed to bypass this issue by dropping all of my foreign key restraints. While I still have foreign key indexes that refer to other tables, as far as my mySQL database is concerned, this is just field that holds an unsigned integer. I enforce the relationships between my models in my application like [this](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships), and it has worked for me so far.

Comment: Yep. I've seen this approach done before. Probably not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You're specify the `car` table but the table name is `cars`.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('rides', function(Blueprint $table) 
    {
        $table->foreign('car_id')
              ->references('id')->on('cars')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```